# What are some example of the use of argentometric titration?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

Like, we use alkalimetric titration to calculate the real concentration of table vinegar. What about argentometric titration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods based on precipitation of silver(I) compounds are collectively called argentometric methods. They are most often used for the determination of chloride ions, but they can be used also for other halides (bromide, iodide) and some pseudohalides (thiocyanate). Titration is in aqueous solution against a solution of silver nitrate of known concentration for silver(I) salts that gives an insoluble precipitate. See [Wikipedia overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentometry) and [titrations.info — Argentometry - Mohr method](http://www.titrations.info/precipitation-titration-argentometry-chlorides-Mohr) for the example of a lab procedure.

It is also possible to use indirect argentometric methods for determination of anions, that create insoluble salts with silver(I) (for example, phosphate $\ce{PO4^{3-}}$, arsenate $\ce{AsO4^{3-}}$ and chromate $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}).$ These methods are based on back titration of excess silver with standardized thiocyanate solution. See [Wolfram Demonstrations Project — Argentometric Titration by Precipitation of Silver Salts](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ArgentometricTitrationByPrecipitationOfSilverSalts/) for more details.